# wrong intel hd graphics on ubuntu 20.4

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, intel, intel-hd

I have intel i3 3210 processor with intel hd 2500 graphics but installed graphics is Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor.
i have installed fresh ubuntu 20.4
Getting very low performance.

when i write bellow command in terminal then

`lspci -nn | grep VGA`

output

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0152] (rev 09)`

Please help me out to install proper graphics intel hd 2500

Comment: Some thing, different names. Intel graphics drivers are open-source and automatically installed. Your driver are the proper drivers.

Comment: Also provide output of `sudo lshw -class display` to see driver in use.

Comment: Please also install `vainfo` utility with `sudo apt-get install vainfo` and then provide output of `vainfo`.